# Disable iOS scrolling when using fancybox?

Tags: ios, fancybox, fullscreen, scrollbars

I'm using fancybox to create a fullscreen gallery on my site. It's a rather long site and when the fancybox is initiated, you can still scroll, which I imagine could be quite confusing to the user. Is there a way I could disable scrolling while the fancy box layer was initiated?

Thanks.

Comment: what version of fancybox? ... fancybox v2.1.3 (latest to date) would do that by default

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem with fancybox. After some googling i found the answer.

```
$.fancybox({
    maxHeight   : '200',
    width       : '38%',
    height      : '70%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    scrolling   : 'no',
    autoDimensions : 'true',
    closeEffect : 'none'
});
```

in your jQuery set

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = // get your scroll view
scrollView.scrollingEnabled = NO;
// initialize your fancybox
scrollView.scrollingEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: is scrolView a propriety piece of css for iOS safari?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question. Are you creating a *web page* on which you'd like to disable scrolling?

Comment: Yes, sorry, should have been more clear. First time I've used this site and I didn't even realize it catered to all sorts of programming.